# how this code (or project) work?(editable ASP Gridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am new in ASP.NET ,I would have editable gridview in asp.net using C# , I found this editable gridview ([Database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/editable_gridview_control/Database_Backup.zip) , [Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/editable_gridview_control/Demo.zip)) in codeproject but i didn't realize how 
its work specially this part of code:`

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
     DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
          {
              DropDownList dp= (DropDownList )e.Row .FindControl ("DropDownList1");
              DataTable dt = load_department();
              for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               ListItem lt = new ListItem();
               lt.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
               dp.Items.Add(lt);
           }
              dp.SelectedValue = drv[3].ToString();
              RadioButtonList rbtnl = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
              rbtnl.SelectedValue = drv[5].ToString();
              CheckBoxList chkb = (CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoxList2");
              chkb.SelectedValue = drv[6].ToString();    
          }              
       }
   }
```

` 
Why she/he do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RowDataBound event fires when you bind the grid to a datasource, say, for example, a datatable.

For each row in the datatable, this code will run, and will, depending on the values in that row, put a value in each column of the grid view.

FindControl is used to find the control with the spcific name on that line of the grid view - remember, it will be repeated many times for as many rows as you have.

Once the control has been found, the value is set.

You are effectively setting up each row of the grid view for each row of the data in your data source.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx for an overview of the intent behind this control.

Answer (score 1):

** [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) Occurs when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control.

**[DataControlRowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx) Specifies the state of a row in a data control for eg.Edit,Insert,Selected etc

** [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx)  Gets the current state of the row with regard to its relationship to the DataRowCollection.

now in that `if condition` your dropdownbox (DropDownList1) is filled and RadioButton and Checkebox are setting up their selected values.